# Duplicate value is put into hashmap

Tags: java, memory, hashmap

Could anyone explain me what happen behind the scenes when a duplicate value is put into `HashMap` ?

```
put(k1,v1)
put(k2,v1)
```

How does it effect the memory?

Comment: It's just like having the same value stored at two different indexes in an array.

Comment: If that helps: Map can't have duplicate keys, there is no problem with having duplicate values. In other words `A->1` `B->1` is OK, but in case of `A->1` `A->2` map will store only one `A->..` pair, the most recently placed one.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely nothing special happens. A new entry is created and inserted somewhere in the underlying structure based on the entry's key. The value of a `HashMap` entry has no bearing on where the entry is placed or how it is retrieved.

To clarify, *the value will be copied in each `HashMap` `Entry`*.

Maybe you are confused about what that value is. First, make the distinction between objects, reference values, and variables. The *value* we've been talking about is a **reference to an object**. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) to understand how that applies.

`HashMap` doesn't care about values. It doesn't check them. It only cares about keys. So when you put the same value

```
map.put(k1,v1);
map.put(k2,v1);
```

the `HashMap` will construct two `Entry` objects, which will both hold (and therefore copy) the value of `v1`, and store those in its underlying structure.

Comment: So what are you saying? when two different keys has the same value. that value is actually being duplicated in the memory? or??

Comment: @rayman Yes, that is what I am saying. The _value_ will be copied in each `HashMap` `Entry` and stored in the underlying structure.

Comment: @rayman: a *HashMap* is a mapping between a *Hashed* key, and a value. The value never gets hashed, only the key is. The uniqueness only affects keys.

Comment: Yes. but I am asking what will happen in the memory. will the value be duplicated?